# JavaScript div inside container div will not execute certain code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div inside of a container (div id="x1") that will **not** execute **specific** commands assigned to it with my doFunc() function. If I place the div **outside** the container, the code runs just fine. What I'm trying to do is make a "shrink picture" button in the top right of the image (I used CSS). When the user clicks the image, it gets bigger, using my large() function, and when the user clicks the X, the picture shrinks and hides the X div. The alert("I tried!") command executes fine when the X div is placed inside the container div, but the resize command will only execute if the X div is outside of it's container (not in the top right of the image where i need it to be.) Anyone with better knowledge of HTML and JavaScript, can you please explain to me what I have to do to get these 2 lines of code to run without having to ditch my "Click the X to close" idea?

```
document.getElementById(containerId).style.width="300px";
document.getElementById(xId).style.display="none";
```

HTML-

```
<div class="container" id="container1" onclick="large('container1','x1')">
<img src="icecream.jpg">
<div class="x" id="x1" onclick="doFunc('container1','x1')">X</div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript-

```
function large(containerId, xId){
document.getElementById(containerId).style.width="600px";
document.getElementById(xId).style.display="block";
}
function doFunc(containerId, xId){
document.getElementById(containerId).style.width="300px";
document.getElementById(xId).style.display="none";
alert("I tried!");
```

Comment: a running demo would help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that's because when you put it inside the container div,the div will also execute when you click the second function, you should put the function in a different div, in my example i put it on the image. (just replace the image)

```js
function large(containerId, xId){
document.getElementById(containerId).style.width="600px";
document.getElementById(xId).style.display="block";
}
function doFunc(containerId, xId){
document.getElementById(containerId).style.width="300px";
document.getElementById(xId).style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img id="img" onclick="large('img','x1')" style="max-width:100%;max-height:100%;" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-v0soe-ievYE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OixOH_h84Po/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg">
 <div class="x" id="x1" onclick="doFunc('img','x1')">X</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below working code.

> The issue you had is, whenever the div `x1` is clicked the event is
>   bubbled to the parent div `container1` which calls its onclick event
>   and increases the width. Hence, when you click on `x1`, it calls first
>   `doFunc` and reduces the width and due to event bubbling the parent
>   got the `onclick` event and triggered `large` event which increases
>   the width again.

Hence, it looks nothing happened.

It has been fixed below by stopping the event bubbling with `e.stopPropagation()`.

```js
function large(containerId, xId){
document.getElementById(containerId).style.width="600px";
document.getElementById(xId).style.display="inline";
}
function doFunc(e, containerId, xId){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
document.getElementById(containerId).style.width="300px";
document.getElementById(xId).style.display="none";
//alert("I tried!");
  }
```

```css
.container
{
  width: 300px; 
 }

.x {
 display: none; 
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container1" onclick="large('container1','x1')">
<img width="100%" src="http://pisces.bbystatic.com//BestBuy_US/store/ee/2015/com/pm/nav_desktops_1115.jpg">
<div class="x" id="x1" onclick="doFunc(event, 'container1','x1')" style="float:right">X</div>
    </div>
```